# Logging exceptions in Spring MVC using Log4j2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j2

I am trying to configurate Spring and Log4j2 to log exceptions with stack traces to file. The problem is that default configuration log only one line, for example:

```
2016-11-21 23:14:28 WARN  MvcLogger:189 - Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: java.lang.Exception: some message
```

This line is printed by SimpleMappingExceptionResolver created as below:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver(){
    SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

    Properties mappings = new Properties();
    mappings.setProperty("Exception", "exception");

    resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    resolver.setDefaultErrorView("error");
    resolver.setWarnLogCategory("example.MvcLogger");
    return resolver;
}
```

So I looked into source code of AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver wich i superclass of SimpleMappingExceptionResolver and I found this:

```
protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (this.warnLogger != null && this.warnLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        this.warnLogger.warn(buildLogMessage(ex, request));
    }
}
```

and I realized that it can't print stack trace under exception. To resolve this problem I must extend SimpleMappingExceptionResolver and override logException method, but really there is no simplier method to do this?

Here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/money-manager/appLog.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <appenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.corriel" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
            <appender-ref ref="File" level="DEBUG" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share log4j config file?

Comment: Ok, I added log4j2.xml to question

Comment: Can you give the line in your code that is producing the output?

Comment: Its just test for log4j configuration:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/categoryToExpense", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, BigDecimal> categoryToExpense() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("some message");`

Comment: It seems there are no simpler solutions :(. You have already said about one way. Another way can be editing AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver class and build api on your own.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.